# How to handle Audio continously with Landscape and portrait in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, landscape-portrait

I have created audio in one activity with media player. I have run properly with start, pause, resume also but when I rotate my screen with landscape or portrait mode my song is playing twice.

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this, R.raw.subhanallah);
        Log.e("Song is playing", "in  Mediya Player ");

        mp.setLooping(false);
        mp.start();

        System.out.println("Media Plyer Is Start !!!");
        prefsEdit.putBoolean("mediaplaying", true);
        prefsEdit.commit();
        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);

        System.out.println("B4 button Click!!!!");


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
        boolean isPlaying = prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying", false);
        if (isPlaying)
        {
            mp.pause();
            int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.e("Current ", "Position -> " + position);
            prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
            prefsEdit.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        mp.start();

        boolean isPlaying = prefs.getBoolean("mediaplaying", false);
        if (isPlaying) {
            int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
            mp.seekTo(position);
            // mp.start();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { 
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on `SharedPreferences` value in `onPause()`. Use it only to start player in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"` to your activity element in your manifest

Comment: I have already done with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard" but none of the use .Whever I have change orientation of my screen landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape mode my song is playing abain and again.

Answer (score 1):

When rotating your activity is destroyed and re-created which is why it starts to play twice. You should play music in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: But service is used only for system background then how to use media player in service and call in onCreate() method in Activity.I want playing the audio file only with Activity life cycle (start , stop , pause , and resume).So how can I done with media player with service .

Comment: In `onStart()` call `startService(intent)`, in `onStop()` call `stopService(intent)`. If you only need it to play while in the activity you could create an AsyncTask to play the music as that is attached to the activity lifetime anyway.

Remember using a service still runs code on the app's main thread, you still need to start a thread in the service to ensure you dont get an ANR error.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this working? If so, please mark this as the answer. Cheers.